# Create different Kafka topics for different tweets' subjects?

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming, tweepy

I'm trying to stream data from Twitter about different subjects: music, politics, sports, etc. in order to display the tweets in a map. The aim is that the user can 'filter' the tweets she/he is watching (by timestamp, by subject...). I'm using Kafka, Spark Streaming and Tweepy for this project.

Each of the mentioned subjects are filtered by several keywords/hashtags. You can see an example below.

```
music_keywords = ['music', 'song', 'The Voice', '#Eurovision']
politics_keywords = ['politics', 'democracy', 'government']
sports_keywords = ['sports', 'football', 'tennis', 'basketball', 'Real Madrid']
```

Because of that, I'm doubting between creating a Kafka topic for each one or just identifying them by a key and publish them to the same topic.

I've read that partitioning is highly recommend to preserve the order of publication of Kafka messages and consume them in that order. But that is not a problem for me, as I don't care about order and all the tweets will be consumed by the same consumer. I'm also afraid that the fact of being strictedly sequential could cause latency when consuming.

Another solution I've thought about is just filter the tweets by all of the keywords of all of the subjects and then, when parsing the data in the consumer, classify them (with a switch, for example) regarding each tweet's text.

I don't know which approach could be the best for my problem, also considering that I'm using the Standard Twitter API and I don't have a high volume of incoming data.

Comment: If you want to filter by timestamp, specifically, you probably want to send Kafka data to some database that you can actually to time-based searching on... At that point, I don't think it really matters how many topics you have, as long as they end up in the same system